# Fink: How to do insert into multiple tables within a transaction

Tags: transactions, apache-flink, flink-streaming

we have some java code which is consuming data from Kafka now, we are now trying to rewrite the job with Flink, I have some code like below to split the incoming event into multiple object which sink into different tables, but within a transaction, so if one of sink failed, rollback the transaction. How to do it in Flink? Thanks

```
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            // insert history
            insertTable1(...);

            // add new status
            insertTable2(...);

            // handle findings
            insertTable3(...);

            // handle incidents
            insertTable4(...);

            conn.commit();
```

Comment: The tables you are writing to, are they also backed by Kafka topics?

Comment: no, just mysql db @DavidAnderson. I was thinking just sink it in sequence, I thought that maybe the way of flink style, cause I think if one of sink failed, can recover by itself, right?

Answer (score 1):

Flink does two-phase commits in concert with checkpointing. And each instance of the sink(s) has its own transactions.

All of the sinks first do the pre-commit phase. If any of the pre-commits fail, the whole checkpoint will fail and everyone will rollback in a coordinated fashion. However, once all of the pre-commits succeed, then Flink proceeds to the commit phase. At this point, Flink assumes that all of the transactions will eventually succeed. If this assumption is violated, e.g. by one of the transactions timing out, then data can be lost.

This is explained in more detail in [An Overview of End-to-End Exactly-Once Processing in Apache Flink (with Apache Kafka, too!)](https://flink.apache.org/2018/02/28/an-overview-of-end-to-end-exactly-once-processing-in-apache-flink-with-apache-kafka-too/).

Comment: so, for example, I have 5 tablesink in the main process, aren't they independent sink?

process() {

stream = getSource();

sinktable1() // extract message from stream, then sink
sinktable2() // extract status from stream, then sink
.....
}

Comment: They are semi-independent. None of them will commit anything until all have successfully completed the pre-commit phase.

Comment: thanks, David. I went through the doc you sent and understood the two-phase commit mechanism. But, I have a requirement that needs to sink in sequence, basically, we need to delete data from the table first, then insert new data. How can we achieve this using sink?

Comment: Flink's JDBC Table sink can be used in either UPSERT mode, where it uses the primary key defined on the table as the basis for doing an UPDATE, or in INSERT mode where each record is appended to the table.

Answer (score -1):

In Flink, you can achieve transactional writes to multiple sinks by using the Two-Phase Commit (2PC) pattern. Flink provides built-in support for 2PC through the FlinkKafkaProducer, which allows you to atomically commit or abort the writes to multiple sinks based on a transactional context.

Here's how you can rewrite your Java code to achieve transactional writes using Flink:

Create a Flink environment and configure the Kafka producer with exactly-once semantics:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// Configure the Kafka producer with transactional support
Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
producerConfig.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "your_kafka_brokers");
producerConfig.setProperty("transaction.timeout.ms", "60000"); // Set transaction timeout
FlinkKafkaProducer<MyEvent> kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(
    "your_topic",
    new MyEventSerializer(),
    producerConfig,
    FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

Define your data processing logic using Flink DataStream API:

```
DataStream<MyEvent> events = env.addSource(...);

DataStream<MyTable1Record> table1Records = events.flatMap(new Table1Mapper());
DataStream<MyTable2Record> table2Records = events.flatMap(new Table2Mapper());
DataStream<MyTable3Record> table3Records = events.flatMap(new Table3Mapper());
DataStream<MyTable4Record> table4Records = events.flatMap(new Table4Mapper());
```

Use the TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction to implement the transactional writes:

```
table1Records.addSink(new TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction<MyTable1Record, KafkaTransactionContext>(
    new FlinkKafkaProducer<>("table1", new MyTable1RecordSerializer(), producerConfig),
    new KafkaTransactionContextSerializer()) {

    @Override
    protected KafkaTransactionContext beginTransaction() {
        // Start the Kafka transaction and return a transaction context
        return new KafkaTransactionContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void preCommit(KafkaTransactionContext transaction) {
        // Perform pre-commit actions (optional)
    }

    @Override
    protected void commit(KafkaTransactionContext transaction) {
        // Commit the Kafka transaction
        transaction.commitTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    protected void abort(KafkaTransactionContext transaction) {
        // Abort the Kafka transaction
        transaction.abortTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    protected void invoke(KafkaTransactionContext transaction, MyTable1Record value, Context context) throws Exception {
        // Send the record to Kafka within the transactional context
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("table1", value));
    }
});
```

Repeat the above step for each sink (table2, table3, table4) using the corresponding mappers and serializers.
By using the TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction, Flink will automatically manage the transactional state and ensure that all writes succeed or fail as a single transaction. If any sink fails, Flink will abort the transaction and trigger a rollback of all the other sinks within that transaction.

Make sure to handle exceptions and failures appropriately, especially within the preCommit, commit, and abort methods, to ensure proper transactional behavior.

Comment: Where do we define all the tablesinks belong to the same transaction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, cocobot!

Both of your answers so far here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.